# Anime where a fighter turns into a card after losing

Tags: mushrambo

There was an anime that I grew up on as a youngster and I don't remember much about it other than that when two fighters fought, the loser turned into a card that the other could use as power. Help me, please.

Comment: it has nothing to do with naruto

Comment: How old are you now?

Answer (score 3):

Could it be [Shinzo/Mushrambo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinzo)?

[image]

I've never seen the show myself, but a lot of people mention it being a show where people fight each other and the loser turns into a card, which could be eaten to make the guy more powerful.